# How to force browser to show image 3 inches wide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

Having simple HTML code

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img  ... >
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and CSS styles

```
* {
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
html {
    position:relative;
    min-width:342px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:319px
}
table {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-171px;
    margin-top:-159px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%
}
img, table {
    width:342px;
    height:319px;
}
```

All together accessible with **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bY2SM/)** (there is just red box image in this example),

a picture of fixed size is centered horizontally and vertically. It is quite simple, however it does not look nice on phones that have high screen resolution, when most of screen looks white and in the middle of screen is something, that user would not recognize without zoom-in.

Using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` would not help much, as if mobile phone has over thousand of pixels width on just 4 inches, image is still just about inch wide.

I read a lot about screen resolution issues and I haven't find any solution, as most browsers assume 1 inch is 96 pixels, so working with `in`, `pt` or `pc` goes nowhere.

How can I force browser to make the image inside of html page let's say 3 inches wide?

Comment: First of all, static image size on mobile is something you shouldn't be doing unless it's an icon/thumb picture. Second, why don't you just serve the image the size you want it to be?

Comment: Most browsers don't *assume* 1 inch is 96 pixels, this is defined in the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - I should use different wording, but regardless... it is 96px per quasi-inch (http://jsfiddle.net/gNqRF/), not real inch, so it is useless!

Comment: Just use `3in` instead of `1in`: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/gNqRF/1. 96 * 3 = 288.

Comment: I have changed my answer to provide a workaround. Take a peek when you get a chance.

Comment: Have you tried `max-width` ? I don't know if it works for you, but here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/bY2SM/5/

Comment: @epascarello CSS Media Queries cannot be use to determine physical screen dimensions! :'-(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is just not possible. The `in` measurement is for print, not for video output. If you use `width:8in;height:11.5in` then it will print on to paper as a standard Letter sized area.

Even on screens of the same resolution, an inch will be different. For example, a phone versus a projector. They can both have high resolution, but the pixels in an inch on a projected image will tiny. Moreover, there is no way to detect what the size of the projected image will be whatsoever because it is controlled at the lens of the projector (picture a 20ft projector screen with a width of 2000px, that is 8 pixels per inch).

The only possible way to accomplish a pixel to inch measurement would be to hardcode it after direct measurement of each mobile device supported and then determine a way to specifically detect the presence of each one of those mobile devices. This is non trivial and will more than likely not work as a solution.

All in all, it is not possible to force the browser to show 3 real inches of size because it really has no clue what that means. Stick to percentages, or make a library of pixel to inch conversions for supported mobile devices.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be impossible, that's why I open this bounty to find a workaround that would be enough close to the idea of measurements in inches. I made simple fiddle that measure viewport in default monospace medium size characters. See http://jsfiddle.net/Suvs7/show/. This may be close solution, as most of devices got around 17 characters per inch. I would appreciate if you can test this fiddle on your end with available devices to find out how many characters per inch you experience. Thank you.

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ - I [tested your fiddle](http://i.imgur.com/p5iM9bd.png). I ended up getting 8 pixels per character. Physical measurement was 2 characters per inch.

Comment: Travis, your test comes with 128 characters wide viewport and you wrote that you got 2 characters per inch? Do you really have 64" wide screen? (`128=2*64`) What devices did you use for this test?

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ - I use an [optoma projector](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/optoma-xga-dlp-multimedia-projector/8827452.p?id=1218910868576&skuId=8827452#tab=overview). It is good to reduce eye strain to have your viewing surface as far away as possible.

Comment: Okay, that make sense that for such distance people need to have it 8x larger. Well, I was hoping to test it on mobile devices.

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ - I have an older iPhone 3g. Its display is 2 inches wide. It is roughly 28 characters per inch.

Comment: Thanks. It means your iPhone default font is much smaller.

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ - Indeed, the font size will also affect the characters per inch. My measurement was from the google news page. I measured the text in one of the blurbs (not the title).

Comment: Google News don't use default monospace medium size font, I believe. Any chance to test my fiddle on your iPhone, please?

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ - Unfortunately jsfiddle crashes on my iphone. It is rather annoying when trying to test touch detection and other features at times. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this post, http://ehikioya.com/online-ruler/  You must still "calibrate" though, there is simply no way around this as others have stated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "in" width identifier in CSS that is "Inches".

So you would just need to set up a:

```
width: 3in;
```

rule for that image.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

But that's if you're writing CSS code in a corporate environment for people that don't understand anything about the web.

As the comments mention below - a CSS inch is not a REAL inch, though. And that's where media queries come into play. Instead of worrying about how things look in inches, you need to switch to pixels and use media queries to resize your image dynamically based on screen sizes.

[Here](http://pixelyzer.com/image_size_calculator.html) is a link to a page that explains how digital displays translate into physical inches and includes a calculator program. It's all about the DPI.

As you try different options in the dropdown, you'll see why it's sort of an impossible question to answer with precision. If you're only worried about a single display, then by all means use their calculator and get an exact pixel width for an inch and use that in your CSS.

Comment: Take a ruler and measure it - what you got?

Comment: Fair enough, I updated my response in regards to "real" inches. I've had to sit through lectures from corporate clients on inches and then walk them through different resolutions on their own monitor to show them how silly it is. Depending on how that goes, I sometimes then have to tailor the CSS to their own resolution just so that I can get paid. Web dev is fun!

Comment: You're being kinda hostile, but I'm going to tack that on to you being frustrated? I can't answer your question, nor can anyone else.

The web isn't in inches, it's in pixels. Every viewing device has a fixed width and height in pixels. If you haven't already, I suggest reading up on responsive design and media queries.

If you have, and are still focused on quasi-inches and inches, then I'm sorry, and I mean this in the nicest way, but the web isn't going to be a friendly place for you as a designer. Printable margins in inches and centimeters are for physical media and not for digital media.

Comment: You can NOT make that calculation when the resolution is unknown!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. And that is what I"m saying here: "As you try different options in the dropdown, you'll see why it's sort of an impossible question to answer with precision. If you're only worried about a single display, then by all means use their calculator and get an exact pixel width for an inch and use that in your CSS."

Like it or not, I have answered your question.

The web works with percentages and pixels. That's the beauty of @media CSS rules used in responsive designs, that they can resize everything based on specific breakpoints of device resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate the intensity of the opinions on this matter, HTML/CSS is being used for much more than just page display on screens.  It has actually an excellent system for describing pages in books, catalogs and other printed/digital media.

The W3C has defined an extension of CSS to handle "Paged Media" where the content is separated into separate "surfaces" (pages) of fixed size.  The [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#intro) is still in draft form but is far enough along that there are several libraries supporting it ([weasyprint](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is one that I have used for conversion to PDF).

The format is pretty powerful and allows for fixed page sizes, headers, footers, page numbering, separate formats for left/right, title and chapter pages.
For example, here is a simple style sheet definition for page headers and numbers (taken from W3C definition document):

```
@page {
  size: 8.5in 11in;
  margin: 10%;

  @top-left {
    content: "Hamlet";
  }
  @top-right {
    content: "Page " counter(page);
  }
}
```

I mention this, because the OP's question becomes legitimate and important when working with paged-media where fixed dimensions for text, images and objects become important.

For our work, we need to programmatically define reports which, while they may not be printed, need to be viewed in paged format or converted to PDF for storage and possible printing.

There are a number of good tutorials on it: [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/) and [here](https://www.pagedmedia.org/paged-media-approaches-part-1-of-2/) among others.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can add some working fiddle to show your concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a pretty good approximation by having the user calibrate what an "inch" is and adjusting everything accordingly. There are several storage options where you can save what the user has calibrated and multiple ways to create the calibrator.

```
$("img").each(function () {
    $(this).data("width", $(this).width());
    $(this).data("height", $(this).height());
})
$("#calibrator").on("change", function () {
    var multiplier = this.value;
    $("img").each(function () {
        var newWidth = $(this).data("width") * multiplier;
        var newHeight = $(this).data("height") * multiplier
        $(this).css({
            width: newWidth,
            height: newHeight
        });
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bY2SM/8/

Answer (score 0):

This question is ill-formed and it's highly likely that whatever you want to do is wrong, but I'll leave you with the benefit of the doubt and the following code snippet:

```
function getPPI(){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width="1in";

  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  body.appendChild(div);

  var ppi = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(div, null).getPropertyValue('width');
  body.removeChild(div);

  return parseFloat(ppi);
}

image.width = 3 * getPPI();
```